# SQL - selecting the most recently added rows from a table with a given range

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that has an integer `id` (primary key) and `timestamp` date added columns (among others).

what would the syntax to **extract the `id` values for the ten most recent "date added" values** look like?

Comment: I use Transact-SQL, but: `SELECT \`id\` FROM \`table\` ORDER BY \`date added\` DESC LIMIT 10`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we go by the title of your question (10 most recent rows):

```
SELECT `id`
  FROM `table`
 ORDER BY `date added` DESC
 LIMIT 10
```

If we go by what you say in your question (10 most recent values of date added):

```
SELECT `id`
  FROM `table`
 WHERE `date added` IN ( SELECT DISTINCT `date added`
                           FROM `table`
                          ORDER BY `date added` DESC
                          LIMIT 10 )
```

As I noted in my comments, I use Transact-SQL primarily so you might need to adjust for any gaps in my MySQL knowledge.

Comment: I suppose my title could have been worded better; it is the latter I'm looking for. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT id
  FROM `table`
 ORDER BY `date added` DESC LIMIT 10
;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have an auto incremented primary key you could also order by id:

```
SELECT `id`
 FROM `table`
 ORDER BY `id` DESC
 LIMIT 10
```

The advantage is that id already has a index so you can sort by it very fast. But you need to be sure that you don't mess around with the id so it is always in the right order.

If you use `date added` anyway you should create an index for it. But the table will use a little bit more space this way.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id FROM `table` ORDER BY `date added` DESC LIMIT 10
```